# MVC view element aligning problem

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-2

This is probably a dump question but I can't find a way to align the second  elements on the view. Tried using width on the display-labels but it does not affect anything; the display-fields start immediatelly after the labels. What should to manipulate the width of the labels?

**Update**

```
<div>
    <div class="display-label">Name:</div >
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.personalInfo.FirstName + " " + Model.personalInfo.LastName%></div >
</div>
<div>
    <div class="display-label">Date of Birth:</div >
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.personalInfo.DOB.ToShortDateString() %></div >
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
.display-label
{
margin: 0.5em 0;
font-weight:bold;
padding: 0.5em 0;
width: 10em;
float: left;
}

.display-field
{
margin: 0.5em 0;
padding: 0.5em 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the labels in divs with `float: left` rule and fixed width. Also put the values in divs.

```
<div>
    <div class="display-label">Name:</div>
    <div><%: Model.personalInfo.FirstName + " " + Model.personalInfo.LastName%></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="display-label">Date of Birth:</div>
    <div><%: Model.personalInfo.DOB.ToShortDateString() %></div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
.display-label {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

and a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvsPZ/1/).

Or if for some cryptic reason you cannot change those spans to divs you could also display them as blocks (a.k.a divs):

```
.display-label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

.display-field {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I added your reccomendations but now it got really messed up. Fileds now appear higher than the labels! Updated the question with the css I am using.

Comment: It works fine if I remove the margins and paddings... Why is this happening?

Comment: @Tsarl, it's happening because you have margins and paddings :-)

Comment: I suspected it :P So I shouldn't be using paddings and margins in general to avoid these weird problems?

Answer (score 1):

Apply your margin and padding to the parent div